# How to extract and capture particular multiple words using or option in REGEX.?

Tags: javascript, regex, python-2.7

I have small query and requirement regarding REGEX.

I have set of files in one location in that i want to capture only some files that are important:

The INPUT is:

````
```
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user 51200310 Dec  2 15:55 osm_ms01.log00025
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user 51200201 Dec  2 19:52 osm_ms01.log00026
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user 51200010 Dec  2 23:49 osm_ms01.log00027
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  1251657 Dec  3 02:53 osm_ms01.out00098
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user    14534 Dec  3 03:23 osm_ms01.out00099
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  2124021 Dec  9 00:42 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  3406259 Dec  9 00:44 osm_ms01.out00100
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user    14632 Dec  9 00:55 osm_ms01.out00101
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  4142712 Dec  9 01:00 osm_ms01-diagnostic.log
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user 51200768 Dec  9 13:20 osm_ms01.log00028
drwxr----- 2 osm_user osm_user     4096 Dec 11 00:58 metrics
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  1101990 Dec 11 01:38 osm_ms01.out
-rw-r----- 1 osm_user osm_user  1150229 Dec 11 01:38 osm_ms01.log
```
````

In above input i just want to capture these below files:

````
```
access.log
osm_ms01-diagnostic.log
osm_ms01.log
```
````

I tried this below REGEX but i cant find any solution.

The regex is used

`1) .*\.log.*
2) (access.log|osm_ms01.log|osm_ms01-diagnostic.log)`

In second regex i can captured information but its capturing information that not necessary.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
(access.log|osm_ms01.log|osm_ms01-diagnostic.log)$
```

for matching from the ending

Comment: Thanks One small doubt the one you given also working and @naurel given one regex with boundary that also matching. What diffrence between $ and /b. which one is efficient to use. ?

Comment: /b is for matching word breaks, while $ is to match line end

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is similar to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593470/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-multiple-words-on-different-locations)

If you put each line into an array element, and check if the the string if it contains what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your .log isn't followed by another char.
To do so you can check for the word boundary before and after :

```
\b(access.log|osm_ms01.log|osm_ms01-diagnostic.log)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE8jL4/2)

All credit goes to @stribizhev

Comment: Perhaps, `(?<=\s)` and `(?=\s)` can be replaced with a mere `\b`. Something like `\b(access\.log|osm_ms01\.log|osm_ms01-diagnostic\.log)\b`