# Regular expression "all three in any order and nothing more"

Tags: regex

I need to make a reg expression that will match following conditions:

1) mathing only if it has three words
2) not separated or separated by semicolon (;)
3) in any order
4) all of words should be included, otherwise it will not match

I tried this one:

```
^(?=(.*;|)one)(?=(.*;|)two)(?=(.*;|)three).*$
```

but somehow it mathes variants like oneasfafasfsaf;two;three
it`s wrong

please, help!

P.S. sometimes it`s needed to have more than three, but i want to understand the core

Comment: post input and expected output

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911053/regular-expression-to-match-all-words-in-a-query-in-any-order

Comment: not, it`s actually not a duplicate, i  need to have only these words and nothing more in the string. Sorry, if i forgot to mention.
Well "one;two;three", "three;two;one" "threetwoone" should be matched
"one;two;four;three","one;one;two;three" - should not be matched

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) all 3 and check for each exists, then, if string is only composed of the 3 words:

```
^(?=.*?(one))(?=.*?(two))(?=.*?(three))(?:(?:\1|\2|\3);?){3}$
```

See [test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tI4tW9/1) (explanation on the right); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Answer (score 1):

```
(one|two|three);?(?!\1)(one|two|three);?(?!\2)(one|two|three)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/41