# Search for property values within specific HTML tags

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio, within a large ASP.NET project I need to find all images that have a HTML class of "info".  These images however can be applied using the following approaches:

1. Directly in the page, `<img alt="..." title="..." class="info" />`
2. As an ASP image, `<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="..." CssClass="info" />`
3. As string concatenation, `Dim s = "<img .... class=""info"" />"` (notice double quotes)

Other hurdles are that images may have multiple classes, e.g. `<img ... class="foo info bar" />`, so a search for `class="info"` doesn't work.  Also, other HTML elements also use this class, but should be ignored, e.g. `<p class="info">Foo</p>`.

I need a Regular Expression for searching that provides the following logic:

1. Must contain `img` or `asp:Image` (case-insensitive)
2. Must contain `class` or `CssClass` (case-insensitive)
3. Must contain `info` (case-sensitive)

Comment: @Downvoter - any suggestions please on why you voted to close?  I am trying to find a string containing three specific values, I don't see how that's too broad...

Comment: At a guess, the down/closevote is because there are certain categories of question that Stack Overflow receives free work requests at a fairly high volume. They are: regular expressions, mod_rewrite rules, SQL queries and XPath expressions. In any of these cases, it is important to show what you have tried, to distinguish your question from someone who has not made an attempt at all.

Comment: Since your target text is HTML, can you use an HTML parser? Regex feels like the wrong tool for the job here anyway.

Comment: Argh okay.  I had an example in RegExr but cleared it after an hour of swearing.  I'll re-create it then post back.  Hold those downvotes...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the Visual Studio doesn't accept regular expressions that are pasted verbatim.

The test I did worked fine online ([see working example](http://regexr.com/3gg39))

```
/(img|asp:Image)(?=.*class\b)(?=.*\binfo\b).*$/igm
```

However, this failed to find anything in Visual Studio.  I didn't realise that I needed to remove the start and end characters.   Visual Studio required this revision, which works fine:

```
(img|asp:Image)(?=.*class\b)(?=.*\binfo\b).*$
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911776/792888) which was a lead in the right direction.