# Count rows in a 2d array which contain one of multiple search strings in a specific column

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, whitelist, preg-grep

I'm trying to filter a multidimensional array and return the number of entries found for a given category.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid any use of foreach. Right now looking into using [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) but getting array to string conversion error. I'm doing this :

```
//filter array with category name
$category_array = array('T-Shirt','Men');
$filter_category = (array_intersect($products['result'], $category_array));
var_export($filter_category);//return data of filtered entries
echo $row_count=count($filter_category);//return number of entries
```

The desired result should return the exact same array seen below but only with filtered entries. If there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do. I'm opened!

**This is what the data looks like unfiltered**

```
$products={
        "code": 200,
        "result": [
            {
                "id": 121935189,
                "external_id": "5d27b7962ac2c1",
                "name": "RPROD7742019 Dark Green Bush Camo Men's T-Shirt ",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121934788,
                "external_id": "5d27b641b1f568",
                "name": "RPROD2282019 FOREST GREEN CAMO Men's T-shirt",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121934520,
                "external_id": "5d27b555048158",
                "name": "RPROD7542019 Men's Rash Guard T-Shirt Sweatshirt Long Sleeve",
                "variants": 7,
                "synced": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 121934241,
                "external_id": "5d27b467b817b4",
                "name": "RPROD4952019 Men's T-shirt",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121933767,
                "external_id": "5d27b34c3133a2",
                "name": "RPROD5872019 Men's T-shirt ",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121933319,
                "external_id": "5d27b12e253032",
                "name": "RPROD7662019 DARK GREEN CAMO Men's T-Shirt - Men",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121931543,
                "external_id": "5d27afd7c949b8",
                "name": "RPROD1192019 Jungle Camo Men's T-Shirt - Men",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121930567,
                "external_id": "5d27ae02dd00a8",
                "name": "RPROD7572019 Camo Short sleeve men’s t-shirt - Men",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121930354,
                "external_id": "5d27ad2a338399",
                "name": "RPROD8412019 Camo Men's T-shirt - Men",
                "variants": 6,
                "synced": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 121665999,
                "external_id": "5d251acde94bc7",
                "name": "RPROD3042019 Champion Dad Cap Trucker Cap Men",
                "variants": 2,
                "synced": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 121665890,
                "external_id": "5d251a50cb6a82",
                "name": "RPROD7162019 Vintage Cotton Twill Cap Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 3,
                "synced": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 121665703,
                "external_id": "5d2519cba9fea7",
                "name": "RPROD4872019 Dad hat Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 1,
                "synced": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 121665596,
                "external_id": "5d251972bd8b36",
                "name": "RPROD2492019 Dad hat Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 1,
                "synced": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 121665533,
                "external_id": "5d25193756ac83",
                "name": "RPROD5362019 Trucker Cap Dad hat Men Women",
                "variants": 5,
                "synced": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 121665382,
                "external_id": "5d2518ae661cf3",
                "name": "RPROD3082019 Cotton Cap Trucker Cap Dad Hat Men Women",
                "variants": 7,
                "synced": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 121665266,
                "external_id": "5d2518395f7b28",
                "name": "RPROD6372019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 1,
                "synced": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 121665141,
                "external_id": "5d2517dc928059",
                "name": "RPROD8112019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 9,
                "synced": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 121664869,
                "external_id": "5d25171b371fa4",
                "name": "RPROD7232019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 4,
                "synced": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 121664726,
                "external_id": "5d2516c175ad54",
                "name": "RPROD4112019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 5,
                "synced": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 121664599,
                "external_id": "5d251659e8a218",
                "name": "RPROD7002019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 1,
                "synced": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 121664477,
                "external_id": "5d251609908887",
                "name": "RPROD3232019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 5,
                "synced": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 121664346,
                "external_id": "5d2515ade45543",
                "name": "RPROD6702019 Trucker Cap - Men Women",
                "variants": 5,
                "synced": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 121664113,
                "external_id": "5d2515167e62e4",
                "name": "RPROD9422019 Cotton Cap Dad Hat Women Men",
                "variants": 8,
                "synced": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 121663700,
                "external_id": "5d2513fb5e6572",
                "name": "RPROD2552019 Cotton Trucker Cap Dad Hat Men Women",
                "variants": 4,
                "synced": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 121663350,
                "external_id": "5d251304231b28",
                "name": "RPROD2762019 Trucker Cap Men Women",
                "variants": 9,
                "synced": 9
            }
        ],
        "extra": [],
        "paging": {
            "total": 75,
            "offset": 0,
            "limit": 25
        }
    }
```

Comment: `preg_grep` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays.  You're also giving the wrong arguments. You can only give it one regular expression.

Comment: Can you show what the `$products['result']` array looks like?

Comment: And what do you expect `$fl_array` to be?

Comment: `array_intersect` also only works with 1-dimensional arrays. This is true of all the built-in array searching functions.

Comment: `array_intersect()` doesn't know that it should look in the `Name` column. It also doesn't do substring matching, it looks for exact matches.

Comment: whats the match criteria, all of those have "men" in the name, so they would all be filtered - no?  `return the number of entries found for a given category` whats a category...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$category_array = array('T-Shirt', 'camo');

print_r(
  array_intersect_key(
      $products['result'],
      preg_grep(
          '/(?=.*\b'.implode('\b)(?=.*\b', $category_array).'\b)/i',
          array_column($products['result'], 'name')
      )
  )
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121935189
            [external_id] => 5d27b7962ac2c1
            [name] => RPROD7742019 Dark Green Bush Camo Men's T-Shirt 
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121934788
            [external_id] => 5d27b641b1f568
            [name] => RPROD2282019 FOREST GREEN CAMO Men's T-shirt
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121933319
            [external_id] => 5d27b12e253032
            [name] => RPROD7662019 DARK GREEN CAMO Men's T-Shirt - Men
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121931543
            [external_id] => 5d27afd7c949b8
            [name] => RPROD1192019 Jungle Camo Men's T-Shirt - Men
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121930567
            [external_id] => 5d27ae02dd00a8
            [name] => RPROD7572019 Camo Short sleeve men’s t-shirt - Men
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121930354
            [external_id] => 5d27ad2a338399
            [name] => RPROD8412019 Camo Men's T-shirt - Men
            [variants] => 6
            [synced] => 6
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6485524528ce7b90fb5a4b836582ea7503100132)

They all contain "Men" so I am not sure what the filter rules should be.  Anyway, I used "camo" instead, after some tweaks.

PS, if you want to update the array then just do this instead of `print_r`:

```
$products['result'] = array_intersect_key( ... other code ... );
```

I can explain how it works if you want me too.

Comment: `array_diff_key` removes all the matching items, I think he wants to find the matching items.

Comment: So it should be `array_intersect_key`.

Comment: You're imploding the array with `|`. I think he wants to match all of the categories, not any of them. See my answer for how to write that kind of regexp.

Comment: Well considering there is no example of what it should match, all I have to go on is guess work...

Comment: @Barmar - Updated  (PS, I know what lookaheads are), but it was still a good suggestion.  I just wish the question was more explicit.  Lookarounds are about the only thing I haven't mastered in Regex ( I still struggle with them a bit ) ... lol.  So thanks again.

Comment: Before he edited it, there were two variables that he was trying to match, `$category` and `$subcategory`. In that context, it was clear that it needed to match both.

Comment: Lookarounds are tricky for me, too. That happens to be an idiom I could copy from other questions.

Comment: At least its not just me, ha ha.  I find that 90% of the time I don't need them but the 10% that I do it's the only way to do it...  That's probably part of it, I can get away without them in most cases.  I know they work here, matching multiple things because they don't consume any characters...  That and the `.*` wildcard bit.  For example I get that it matches everything up to the "thing" then because it doesn't consume it basically starts from the beginning for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` for this. Turn your category array into a regular expression that matches all the words; see [Regular Expression to MATCH ALL words in a query, in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911053/regular-expression-to-match-all-words-in-a-query-in-any-order). Then use `preg_match()` in the filter function.

```
$regexp = '/(?=.*\bt-shirt\b)(?=.*\bmen\b)/i';
$fl_list = array_filter(function($p) use ($regexp) {
    return preg_match($regexp, $p['name']);
}, $products['result']);
```

I also used `\b` in my regular expressio, to make it match whole words. Otherwise, `men` will match `women`.

Things would be much easier if you had real keywords in your data, rather than trying to match words in a product name.

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to avoid using a loop if possible. I'm now trying to use array_intersect to return a filtered array with category_name and gender and I still get same error.

Comment: I've update the answer to show how to do it with `array_fitler`.

Comment: I would maybe suggest taking `$category_array` as an argument and then build the regex dynamically.  But that should be trivial for them to add.